# Xamarin.Forms: Call to a API using ServiceStack throws exception

Tags: c#, xamarin, servicestack, xamarin.forms

I have a local service made with ServiceStack and I want to call a method from my Xamarin.Forms application:

```
  ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient sc;
  sc = new ServiceStack.JsonServiceClient("http://api.sportsstars.local/");
```

When the debugger reaches the second line, it throws this exception:

> System.TypeInitializationException: An exception was thrown by the
>   type initializer for ServiceStack.ServiceClientBase

Any ideas what could it be?

Comment: What's the inner exception?

Comment: "PclExport.Instance needs to be initialized"

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found out how to avoid the exception. I've put the code in the Droid project and used a DependencyService to call the method from my PCL project. My problem was for Android. If you get the problem for IOS, the other answer may help you.

Answer (score 1):

Have you [initialized the PCL Client](https://github.com/ServiceStackApps/HelloMobile#initializing-pcl-client)? You can configure it by adding:

```
ServiceStack.IosPclExportClient.Configure();
```

To your application on StartUp.

Comment: I've added it, but it says that IosPclExportClient is missing. Also I need for android.

Comment: One more question. I need to reference ServiceStack in the .Droid and .Ios projects too or only in the Portale one?